# Average of a string which has numbers stored from Scanner

Tags: java, string, int, java.util.scanner

I'm new to coding and have been given the task of getting three months average rainfall (November, December, January) from the user using the scanner, and then to average out the three months rainfalls.

I'm obviously doing something wrong as I've initialised average as a string, but don't know how else to initialise the variable? basically I don't know how to convert the user in-putted results for the rainfall into an integer, if someone could help me with my code and how I could correctly average out the three months, than that'd be brilliant, Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class rainfall {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner (System.in);

    String November, December, January;

    String average;

    System.out.println("what is the rainfall for November?");
    November = stdin.nextLine();

    System.out.println("what is the rainfall for December?");
    December = stdin.nextLine();

    System.out.println("what is the rainfall for January?");
    January = stdin.nextLine();

    System.out.println("the rainfall for November is: \t "  + November );
    System.out.println("the rainfall for December is: \t "  + December );
    System.out.println("the rainfall for January is: \t "  + January );

    average = November + December + January/3;
    System.out.println("The average is " + average );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. You need to parse Strings to Integers using `Integer.parseInt()` and then use `String.valueOf()` to set the int / double value back to String.

Comment: As a side note, use lowercase variable names - it is the convention in Java and other languages, and helps make your program more readable. i.e. instead of `November`, write `november`.

Comment: I see, this is a way to change Strings into ints, I didn't think of it this way, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this can fix your problem

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner (System.in);

        double November, December, January;

        double average;

        System.out.println("what is the rainfall for November?");
        November = stdin.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("what is the rainfall for December?");
        December = stdin.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("what is the rainfall for January?");
        January = stdin.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("the rainfall for November is: \t "  + November );
        System.out.println("the rainfall for December is: \t "  + December );
        System.out.println("the rainfall for January is: \t "  + January );

        average = (November + December + January)/3;
        System.out.println("The average is " + average );
      }
```

Comment: Ah, just change it to doubles instead of Strings, thanks